# How can a Django application integrate a legacy webapp written in php

Tags: php, django, web-applications

I am trying to write a Django webapp, and I want to save the development of metrics display page (/monitoring) -- actually it's hardly to beat that legacy php implementation, given that legacy [webapp's](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) functionality / maturity and user familiarity.

Is there any way for me to integrate the legacy php webapp into my django application?

I somewhat feel [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901857/best-way-to-integrate-php-forum-into-django-site) is relevant to what I am thinking of. However, I really would like not to touch the legacy webapp's code, and the suggested way there seems to need it.

Another approach I am thinking of is that I just setup my apache server such that it directs URL "/monitoring" to the existing legacy php webapp, and direct the rest to my django webapp. But this way, I can't control the user sign-in function, which is implemented in the Django webapp for the "/monitoring" page.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion what's proposed in the post you linked is not good at all. First, you should consider "what" you want to integrate.

- Behavior: (functions, business logic, etc).
- Structures: DB connections, operations
- Custom drivers
- Rendering stuff. How the actual system renders a view/page/whatever and show it as it is.

In the post you linked, that guy wanted to integrate everything: He just wanted to get what he previously used to saw in the PHP page and display it as it was in the django app. Honestly, that's not good. I'd suggest (just based on personal experience) that you shouldn't integrate already-rendered pages in your django app.

What you could do, is to integrate functions and behavior. For example, lets say your PHP monitoring system gets you the number of users for a given time period. It has one PHP function:

```
<?php
function show_users($time_period){
   ...
}
?>
```

Instead of getting the HTML from that monitoring system and put it in your Django app, you should just get the behavior. For example, exposing your PHP application throught a REST interface. So, in your Django code you could have:

```
# views.py
def monitoring(request):
    users = monitoring_service('/users/2012/')
    render(request, 'monitoring.html', {'users': users}
```

in your template:

```
# monitoring.html
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
    <li> {{user}} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Basically, you're reusing the functionallity of your PHP app. But, you're taking care of th rendering part. Of course, it's a little more extra work, but, trust me, it's worth it.

**EXTRA:**

I suggested REST because it's a great solution. But you could chose other interface to communicate, like Thrift, Protocol Buffers or MessagePack (just to name a few)

Comment: I think I want to integrate the rendering + functionality. See the rendered page [OUT-OF-BOX](http://markmims.com/images/terasort-ganglia-1.png). I want this page a one page of my webapp.

Comment: But, what do you want to use django for? Just route /monitoring to that system.

Comment: I want to use django to implement pages like  /login, /error_history, /configuration ...

Yeah, I think I want my django app route /monitoring to the above out-of-box page. But how?

Comment: You'll have to set that in your server. You can swicth the authentication part in Ganglia. That'd be easy.